# Convert File .bmp to binary and binary back to File .bmp in Java

Tags: java, bitmap, binary

I'm trying to convert an Image(.bmp) to binary code, then process it, and convert it back. Let's leave the processing part out and just focus on converting.

What I've managed to do for converting image to binary now:

```
    // Image to byte[]
    File file = new File("image.bmp");
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
    WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
    DataBufferByte data = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();

   // byte[] to binary String
   String string = "";
    for (byte b : data.getData()) {
        String substring = Integer.toBinaryString((b & 0xFF) + 0x100).substring(1);
        string = string.concat(substring);
    }

  // Binary string to binary LinkedList<Ingeger> - this part is optional
  LinkedList<Integer> vector = new LinkedList<>();
    for (char c : stringVector.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == '0' || c == '1') {
            vector.add((int) c - 48);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect value.");
            break;
        }
    }
```

At this point I'm converting a File(.bmp) to a binary vector. I'm not sure if it is correct.

Another issue is converting it back to a .bmp file.
I would need to convert my binary vector(or String) into a `byte[]` and back to `File` or image.

I believe the last step would look like this:

```
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("output.bmp");
        fileOutputStream.write(byteArrayFromBinary.getBytes());
```

Can somone help me figure it out? Cause I'm not sure what's exactly wrong with this. Would be thankful for any advice.

Comment: A BMP file is not just all of the image data, which is all you're getting from the raster; it also has, at least, a header. So the resulting `output.bmp` would not be a BMP file. Aside from that, what you're doing is extremely confusing. I can't imagine why you would want to work on the image data as a `LinkedList<Integer>` of all the bits in the raster. I strongly suspect this is an x-y problem, and you would be better off explaining what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: the `LinkedList<Intgeger>` part as I've mentiod is optional. It's just easier for me to work with it(encode it, pass through channel, decode it). I will be doing the same with image, that's why I need it as a binary, and that's why I need to convert it back from binary to .bmp(after processing). But in this thread I'm just focusing on converting from .bmp to binary and back, and I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: Why on earth are you converting that to String, of all things? And using the Schlemiel the Painter algorithm, too? And, um, in case you didn't notice... bmp _is_ binary, and given that it's uncompressed, it's not "encoded" at all. What are you _actually_ trying to accomplish with all this?

Comment: @Nyerguds so yeah, I was doing it wrong, now I posted a solution that worked perfectly for me. Maybe it isn't the best, but it sure worked for me. I spent some time on that, please be kind to review it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of research finally came up with a solution.

To convert BufferedImage with .bmp format to binary:

```
public String imageToVector(BufferedImage image) throws Exception {
        String vectorInString = "";
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
                Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y), false);
            vectorInString = vectorInString.concat(decimalToBinary(color.getRed()));
            vectorInString = vectorInString.concat(decimalToBinary(color.getGreen())); 
            vectorInString = vectorInString.concat(decimalToBinary(color.getBlue())); 
            }
        }
        return vectorInString;
}
```

To convert back from binary vector to BufferedImage with .bmp format:

```
 String[] splittedString = vectorInString.split("(?<=\\G.{8})");

    int i = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
            int red = Integer.parseInt(splittedString[i], 2); 
            i++;
            int green = Integer.parseInt(splittedString[i], 2); 
            i++;
            int blue = Integer.parseInt(splittedString[i], 2); 
            i++;

            Color color = new Color(red, green, blue);

            image.setRGB(x, y, color.getRGB());
        }
    }
```

If you have any additional question please ask, I can explain why I needed this solution.

Comment: You're still using the [Schlemiel the Painter algorithm](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm). For making long strings you should use a StringBuilder to avoid massive slowdowns and extra memory usage. Also, you're splitting per 8, but you're only handling RGB, without A, so the string is only built per 3 bytes. Shouldn't that be 6 then, rather than 8?

Comment: @Nyerguds Thank you, will consider your tips and improve my algorithm! As for the byte count, yes, you're right, I split by 8 because of another use case, but definitely it should be 6 because I'm not using alpha values. The link you provided was helpful, thank you.